# Delete order item on Firebase

Tags: firebase, android-recyclerview

I have the following structure in firebase...

Firebase Database
[image: Firebase Database]

... and these items are listed on a recycler view.

How can I delete an item based on the user's choice if the position on the recycler view is not the same position on the database? I have tried so many things, but none are working.

I know that the node structure should be like this:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseConfig
                                       .getFirebaseDatabase()
                                       .child("pedidos")
                                       .child("id")
                                       .child("itens")
                                       .child(<<user's choice>>);
```

How is it possible to know this? Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to find a way to distinguish the item from others to be able to delete it, right?

Your itens should have unique identifiers then, so you store not array of itens, but a map of it in db. That means you should assign an identifier to your item first, when constructing it and putting into database.

What is field `iten.id`? Is it unique to your itens **in the array**? If so, then change your database structure like that:

```
pedidos
---pedidoUid
------data
------id
------....
------itens
---------itenID
------------your iten data
------------more data...
---------itenID2
------------you got that
```

So you can pass the id of it to the method that deletes the itens.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for your answer! Yes That`s right. These items are an array list, and the numbers 0,1,2 are added automatically when I am inserting data in this node. I don't really control these numbers. the array does it. itens.id is the id that firebase generates also when I am inserting data. Ive tried to access it but it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by adding a new node called index to get the last index of my array list.

Now the structure goes like this:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseConfig.getFirebaseDatabase().child("pedidos").child("id").child("itens").child(index);
```